# Вывод в соответствующие блоки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 4 блока div, в каждом из которых должна вывестись запись в цикле без повторения:

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM news";
            $res = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            $news=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $news[]=$row;
        }

            <div style="width: 100%; float: left;">
            <?php foreach($news as $new):?>  
                                                     //    должен выводиться результат
                <div style="float: left; width: 25%;"><?=$new['id']?></div> // 1
                <div style="float: left; width: 25%;"><?=$new['id']?></div> // 2
                <div style="float: left; width: 25%;"><?=$new['id']?></div> // 3
                <div style="float: left; width: 25%;"><?=$new['id']?></div> // 4
            <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? На первый взгляд код валидный (ну, `?>` перед `<div>` не хватает), и все должно правильно выводиться. Можно много проговорить об архитектуре, но эта штука должна работать (с оговоркой на закрывающий тег php).

Comment: <div class='cpan' style='float:left; width:25%;'><?=$new['id']?></div>

вот так работает правильно